# Separate large JSON object into many different files

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with 10000 data entries like below in a file.

```json
{
    "1":{
        "name":"0",
        "description":"",
        "image":""
    },
    "2":{
        "name":"1",
        "description":"",
        "image":""
     },
     ...
}
```

I need to write each entry in this object into its own file.

For example, the output of each file looks like this:

`1.json`

```json
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "image": ""
}
```

I have the following code, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Can anyone help with this?

```py
import json
  
with open('sample.json', 'r') as openfile:
  
    # Reading from json file
    json_object = json.load(openfile)
```

Comment: There don't seem to be any arrays (lists?) in your code. Perhaps you could elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over all the fields in the outer object, and then create a new file for each inner object:

```py
import json

with open('sample.json', 'r') as input_file:
    json_object = json.load(input_file)
    for key, value in json_object.items():
        with open(f'{key}.json', 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(value, output_file)
```

Comment: Thanks. how do I format the output

Comment: Depends on what kind of format you want. The types of formatting `json` natively handles can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Great. I used indent=4. . I got last question. file name should start from 0 (0.json, 1.json, ....)

Comment: Use `f'{int(key) - 1}.json` for the file name.